# Prime factorization with return being a string

Tags: swift, string, algorithm, prime-factoring

I am trying to solve the following coding challenge:

Given a positive number `n > 1` find the prime factor decomposition of `n`. The result will be a string with the following form:

`"(p1xxn1)(p2xxn2)...(pkxxnk)"`

with the `p(i)` in increasing order and `n(i)` empty if `n(i)` is `1`.

Example: `n = 86240` should return `"(2xx5)(5)(7xx2)(11)"`

I believe I have figured out how to find the prime factors of a number... my problem is that I have no idea how to convert them into the form required by the question (i.e., a string where p(i) is in increasing order). I tried to convert an integer array containing the prime factors into some sort of array of tuples containing factors p and n, but I have been struggling fruitlessly for several hours.

Here is what I have so far:

```
func factors(_ number: Int) -> String {
    var changedNumber = number
    var numberArr = [Int]()

    while changedNumber >= 2 {
        for i in 2...changedNumber {
            if changedNumber % i == 0 {
                numberArr.append(i)
                changedNumber /= i
                break
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Any insight or resources would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `func factors(_ number: Int) -> String`

I think it’s a mistake to make this return the `String` directly. It violates the separation of responsibilities, and makes this hard to reuse.

Imagine elsewhere in a codebase that uses this function, there might be a function which tries to parse the string result of this back into an array to use it in some other way. It may sound ridiculous, but a large number of the questions we get on here are about people trying to build systems to accept silly input from other systems that they should just change instead!

Here's what I would suggest:

```
func primeFactorization(of value: Int) -> (factor: Int, exponent: Int) {
    ...
}

func format(_ primeFactors: [(factor: Int, exponent: Int)]) -> String {
    return primeFactors
        .map { $0.exponent == 1 ? "(\($0.factor))" : "(\($0.factor)xx\($0.exponent))" }
        .joined()

}
```

So you can then do:

```
let factorization = primeFactorization(of: 86240)
// Which results in: [
//     (factor: 2, exponent: 5),
//     (factor: 2, exponent: 1),
//     (factor: 7, exponent: 2),
//     (factor: 11, exponent: 1),
// ]

// Which you can then format as this one question wants:
format(factorization) // => "(2xx5)(5)(7xx2)(11)"
```

For extra points, you could generify the first function into an extension on `BinaryInteger`, which would let you be able to write something like `86240.primeFactorization()`.

Comment: Ooohh, that's what `(2xx5)(5)(7xx2)(11)` means. This question now makes a lot more sense.

Comment: `.join(separator: "")` should be `.joined(separator: "")` or simply `.joined()`

Answer (score 1):

There's lots of ways to handle this. Here's one, off the top of my head:

Write an extension to Int that has the following functions

```
func isPrime() -> Bool

func nextPrime() -> Int.
```

First check to see if the input number n is prime. If it is, return the result as "(nxxx1)" and you're done.

Define a struct primeFactor:

```
struct PrimeFactor {
   let value: Int
   var count: Int
}
```

Create an array of PrimeFactors.

```
func primeFactorsString(of value: String) -> String {
    var primeFactors = [PrimeFactor]()
    var currentPrime = 1
    var remainder = value
    guard !value.isPrime() else { return "(\(value)xx1)" }
    while remainder > 1 {
       currentPrime = currentPrime.nextPrime()
       if remainder % currentPrime == 0 {
          let newPrimeFactor = PrimeFactor(value: currentPrime, count: 1)
          remainder /= currentPrime
          while remainder % currentPrime == 0 {
              newPrimeFactor.count = newPrimeFactor.count + 1
              remainder /= currentPrime
          }
          primeFactors.append(newPrimeFactor)
       }
    }
    // Now loop through your array of primeFactors and build your output string.
    return primeFactors.map { "(\($0.value)xx\($0.count))".joined()
```

Comment: Note that you should ask the question: What's the largest value that could be passed to this function: Then you should pre-build an array of the primes from 2 to `≤sqrt(largest)` and use those pre-calculated prime numbers to write your isPrime ()and nextPrime() functions. That will make your algorithm much more efficient.

Comment: Personal taste, but I’d recommend using a tuple for a data-only, methodless, short-lived value like this.

Comment: @Alexander fair point. And with tuples with named values you get the same benefit as named properties in a struct.

Answer (score 1):

Just make your function group the numbers and then use each sub collection count when creating your string:

```
func factors(_ number: Int) -> String {
    var changedNumber = number
    var numberArr: [[Int]] = []
    while changedNumber >= 2 {
        for i in 2...changedNumber {
            if changedNumber.isMultiple(of: i) {
                if numberArr.last?.last == i {
                    numberArr[numberArr.count-1].append(i)
                } else {
                    numberArr.append([i])
                }
                changedNumber /= i
                break
            }
        }
    }
    return numberArr.reduce(into: "") {
        if let last = $1.last {
            if $1.count == 1 {
               $0 += "(" + String(last) + ")"
            } else {
               $0 += "(" + String(last) + "xx\($1.count))"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
print(factors(86240))   // (2xx5)(5)(7xx2)(11)
```

Comment: You should use reduce(into:) to prevent cow copies on the string, though I think this is better suited to map+join

Comment: @Alexander considering the size of the string it shouldn't make any difference.

Comment: Yep. Though I think the map+join pattern is more readable, personally.